# Нажатие клавиш с помощью python

Tags: python, python-3.x, windows

Нужно симулировать нажатие клавиши на Python. Без использования keyboard

Comment: Пожалуйста, исправьте вопрос, чтобы он отражал конкретную проблему с достаточным количеством деталей для возможности дать адекватный ответ.

Answer (score 1):

этот модуль pyautogui справляется с вашей задачей.

```
import pyautogui

# вы можете указывать нужное количество нажатий кнопки
pyautogui.press('f1',presses=2)
```

Документацию к модулю смотрите [тут](https://pyautogui.readthedocs.io/en/latest/keyboard.html)

Answer (score 0):

Можно реализовать с помощью библиотеки `pyautogui`:

```
import pyautogui
pyautogui.press('нужная_клавиша', presses=количество_нажатий)
```

Перед этим, возможно, нужно будет залезть в терминал/командную строку и написать команду `pip install pyautogui` для скачивания библиотеки.